# Add Media + Quick Edit buttons not working

Tags: themes, uploads, media, theme-twenty-twelve, quick-edit

I just upgraded to Wordpress 3.6.1 and I have an issue, for the default twenty-twelve theme the add media and quick edit buttons work okay but when I created my own custom theme those buttons stopped working.  I have not yet installed any plugins into my site and I have been searching for a solution for a while now, I need some help on this.

These are the scripts I'm currently using in the `header.php` file:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/slider/anythingfader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/js/jquery.simplyscroll.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `"when i created my own custom theme "`: what scripts are you loading with your theme and how? Please, [edit] the Question to add more details.

Comment: Okay i have re-edited my post, you can check it now.